# Delete task associated with Approval Process Deletion

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, approval-process

When A file is uploaded and before it is approved it is deleted how do I delete the task associated with the approval?

I want to automate it so that when the item is deleted so will the task associated with it.

[image]

Comment: The first thing you cannot attach a workflow when an item is deleted. The workflows will trigger after an operation is completed. You mean deletion is soft delete (set a flag in an item?)

Comment: Hi @Sean, welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution :)